# Unable to send text through XPath to an iFrame element using PhantomJS, Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, iframe, xpath, phantomjs

I am looking to send a string of text to an iFrame element using Selenium.
Previously, I could achieve this by using the Firefox driver.

However, when I switched over to PhantomJS, the test runs but the keys were never entered into the iFrame textbox.

Code as follow:

```
driverJS.SwitchTo().Frame(driverJS.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[9]/form/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/span/span[2]/span/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/iframe")));
//Switch to iFrame and locate element.

driverJS.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body")).SendKeys("bump this up!");
//Send keys to /html/body xpath of iFrame

driverJS.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
//Switch out of iFrame
```

The weblink : [here](http://forums.vr-zone.com/other-hardware-components/3382325-corsair-scimitar.html).

The particular text field in question (quick reply field):
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Raw HTML of iframe body, it doesn't have a name hence I'm resorting to xpath:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" tabindex="1" src="" title="Rich text editor, vB_Editor_QR_editor, press ALT 0 for help." style="width:100%;height:100%">
```

I have tried searching for the iframe's frame index with the following code:

```
    System.Console.WriteLine("The total number of iframes are " + iFramList.Count());

    foreach (IWebElement i in iFramList)
    {
        if (driverJS.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[9]/form/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/span/span[2]/span/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/iframe")).Displayed)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
```

The output is I get is:

```
The total number of iframes are 12
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement
```

Which is odd considering, the run WITHOUT the foreach loop results in 13 iframes instead.

Comment: Where do you want to set value [in this link](http://forums.vr-zone.com/other-hardware-components/3382325-corsair-scimitar.html)..??

Comment: Hi,sorry in the "Quick Reply" iframe text box.

Comment: where is this "Quick Reply"  link. I'm not able to see.. could you share screenshot??

Comment: I have edited the question to include an image of the text field. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

make iframe list and try to invoke the switch from there:

```
//look at the list in debug mode and find the iframe index
IList<IWebElement> iFramList = driverJS.FindElement(By.TagName("iframe"));

driverJS.SwitchTo().Frame(index);

//after that you should send the text to textBox not the body, inspect the element and defind it by id or name like in that example

driverJS.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body")).SendKeys("bump this up!");
//Send keys to /html/body xpath of iFrame

driverJS.FindElement(By.Id("<your textBoxId>")).SendKeys("bump this up!");
```

or by name

```
driverJS.FindElement(By.Name("<your textBoxName>")).SendKeys("bump this up!");
```

Comment: Hi, I'm running into an error "'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" when i eneter the first line of your suggestion.

Comment: @user4985, replace `FindElement`, by `FindElements` on the first line.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I wrote a console debug output and it shows there are 13 iframes on page. Do i try them one by one to figure out my particular iframe?

Comment: You can see the object by innerHtml, or for make it dynamic try to find object you know that exist in the frame by doing foreach loop and when it will find it break the loop and return the index

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried  to use a foreach loop as suggested and have updated the question with the resulting output.

Comment: no no in the loop you should search for your iFrame not to print the object reflation one more thing you can do is : driverJS.SwitchTo().Frame(driverJS.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[@title='Rich text editor, vB_Editor_QR_editor, press ALT 0 for help.']")));

Comment: or in the loop switch indexes and look if if(driverJS.PageSource.Contains("some text from your page")) if its true get out from the loop and continue